# Cannot See Directories on Ubuntu 19.10 from Windows 10

Tags: networking, server, ssh, samba

I have a desktop running 19.10.  I would like to use it as a file server on my LAN.  I have set up Open SSH and I am able to access through Putty on my Windows 10 laptop.  Also, I have installed Samba through the terminal.  My laptop sees it on the Network in the file explorer but it says "This folder is empty."

Do I need to set up access to my directories?  I have removed the monitor from this desktop so I would like to make these changes via terminal in Putty.

Comment: Look at sshfs via putty. No changes are needed to your Ubuntu system, since you already have SSH access. How you set it up on the Windows side seems off-topic here, but any good Search Engine has a dozen tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you need to actually create a smb share. It is done by editing configuration file. Most cases, it is fairly tedious job for some reason and often results in frustration and failure.

As a recommendation if you run your desktop headless, is to install a tool called Cockpit. It also has a plugin for Samba(also docker and others).

```
sudo apt install cockpit cockpit-storaged
```

Then install Samba plugin for Cockpit by running

```
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/enira/cockpit-smb-plugin/master/install.sh | sudo bash
```

After that, open browser, enter your desktops local IP adress and add port 9090(for example, 192.168.0.110:9090), then log in with your desktop's credentials(and tick "Reuse my password for privileged tasks" if you want to adjust the settings there). Then you can fairly simply manage and create your SMB shares.

As I am running a headless too, I am not going back to ssh after having Cockpit for sure. You can set a static IP, SMB shares, manage docker, manage Tuned powersaving settings, even virtual machines, if you want and the best part - it has a terminal right there as well.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  Looks very useful.